# Is this verse from Lady Gaga grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> "I want your love and I want your revenge
>   You and me could write a bad romance"

I have always seen "You and I", as opposed to "You and me". I rely on a rule of thumb that if we remove the other person ("you and"), then what remains (I or me) should make grammatical sense.

Here, "Me could write a bad romance" does not make sense, but who am I to question the grammar of an English-speaking singer?

Comment: Your rule of thumb is a good one, but correct grammar is not a requirement in song lyrics or poetry.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's ungrammatical. You would not see it in formal writing. However, idiomatically, *you and me* is used all the time.

Comment: You could add some punctuation if that would please you: "You and me... Could write a bad romance!". But, yeah, your instinct is correct.

Comment: It is strange. Even walls had a slogan "Me and my magnum", which should grammatically be "My magnum and I" - well, this one is more absurd! I think I need to retake grammar lessons :/